# Calculating the average of 10 most recent values of a column in JPQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to create a JPQL query that calculates the average of certain column over the n most recent records. The corresponding MS SQL query would be:

```
select avg(t.value) from (select top 10 * FROM CamaOperationalData order by TimeStamp desc) t
```

Can anybody tell me how to accomplish that without using a native query?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JPQL myself, but a quick Google search for `jpql select top` revealed several possible answers.  Among those is [this one](http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/SELECT-TOP-n-records-Equilent-in-JPQL-td5194742.html), which suggests using this command:

```
query.setMaxResults(n);
```

Comment: The problem is not limiting the number of results of the query, but to make the aggregate function (avg) only use the n topmost columns ordered by a timestamp. And as far as I know there is no way to limit subqueries in JPQL.